# How do Mirror Image, Slow Time, and Illusionist interact?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

When I use Mirror Image with Slow Time equipped, the mirror images also cast Slow Time. Using the Time Warp rune in Slow Time also increases the damage enemies inside the bubble take by 10%. With Illusionist, you can instantly cool down Mirror Image again. If you do this while the Mirror Image Slow Time bubbles exist, those bubbles *still* exist and the mirrors can create new ones again. I have had upwards of 10 bubbles active at a time from this.

[image: Screenshot of tons of Slow Time bubbles at once]

I have a few questions about the interactions here.

Do the Slow Time bubbles from the mirror images have the same effect as my own? Do they have diminished effects? No effect and just a big annoying bubble?

Assuming the mirror bubbles do have an effect, do they stack with your own bubble (particularly interested in the damage bonus from the Time Warp rune), or do they just expand the area?

Forgetting about Mirror Image for a second, if I have two of my *own* Slow Time bubbles active at once via Illusionist, do they stack?

Comment: I had to correct my answer after seeing I was wrong. Added more information and screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't source any of what I will say here. However, based on my experience and **tests** `Mirrored Slow time` will have the same effect of `Slow time` + runes. The visual effect will be inherited from your current equipped runes and gear. Furthermore, effects does not stack with each other (untested, well not really - but seems obvious).

For example, if you have `Slow time` with `Point of no return`, casting it from your hotbar will apply the stun effect for enemies entering or leaving the area. Mirror cast `Slow time` will act the same, as you can see on the example below.

Illusionist will just allow you to cover more ground.

Edit: I stand corrected, stuns do apply on mirrors. See ->

[image]

Comment: This image takes freehand circles to a whole new level.

Comment: This could be really useful, then, if you have as many casts as in my screenshot above. I wonder if there's a limit to how many times they can be stunned overall, even from different casts.

Comment: Tested that as well. Once per enemy, per `Slow Time` (entering or exiting). Basically, if a monster is stun, he becomes immune from other stun of that bubble, but can be stun by others.

Comment: This is a very useful tactic for hardcore wizard :-)

Comment: Also note that the 4- and 6-piece set bonuses for [Delsere's Magnum Opus](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shrouded-mask) only apply to _your_ Slow Time casts, not your Mirror Images'.